how was the name/category of each scripture assigned?
We have so many categories of scripture - Vedas, Upanishads, Brahmanas Aranyakas etc.
Who assigned the name/category of each scripture?
Are there scriptures whose category is disputed - for example Mahapurana vs Upapurana vs Sthalapurana?
